# Initial value problem involving hyperbolic function.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

Let $$y(t):[0, \infty)\to \mathbb{R}$$ be the solution of the problem
$$y'(t)=(1-y^2(t))\cosh y(t)\ \text{for}\ t>0, \ y(0)=y_0.$$

Find the set of real values of $y_0$ such that $y(t)$ mentioned above is bounded.

I don't know how to proceed for solving such equations.

I have written
$$\frac{dy}{(1-y^2(t))\cosh y(t)}=dt.$$

But unable to proceed further. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ODE
$$
y'=(1-y^2)\cosh y=:f(y) \tag{1}
$$
has two fixed points, $y=-1$ and $y=1$. Therefore, if $y_0=\pm 1$, then $y(t)=\pm 1$ for all $t\in[0,\infty)$, so $y(t)$ is obviously bounded in these cases. Now notice that
$$
\begin{cases}
f(y)>0&\text{if $|y|<1,$} \\
f(y)<0&\text{if $|y|>1,$}
\end{cases} \tag{2}
$$
and that, by uniqueness$^{(*)}$, the solution of the IVP $y'(t)=f(y(t))$, $y(t_0)=y_0$ cannot cross the lines $y=\pm 1$ if $y_0\neq \pm 1$. Therefore,

1. If $y_0>1$, then $y(t)$ is in a region where $y'=f(y)<0$, hence $y_0\geq y(t)>1$ for all $t\in[0,\infty)$, so $y(t)$ is bounded;
2. If $-1<y_0<1$, then $y(t)$ is in a region where $y'=f(y)>0$, hence $y_0\leq y(t)<1$ for all $t\in[0,\infty)$, so $y(t)$ is bounded;
3. If $y_0<-1$, then $y(t)$ is in a region where $y'=f(y)<0$, hence $y(t)\leq y_0$ for all $t$ in the domain of $y(t)$, so the latter is bounded above; however, it is *not* bounded below, since the integral
   $$
   t=\int_{y_0}^{y}\frac{du}{(1-u^2)\cosh u} \tag{3}
   $$
   is well-defined for all $y\in(-\infty,y_0]$.

In summary: $y(t)$ is bounded if $y_0\geq -1$, and unbounded below if $y_0<-1$.

---

$^{(*)}$ It's not difficult to show that the ODE $(1)$ satisfies the hypotheses of the [Picard–Lindelöf theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem).

Comment: Very nicely explained. Thank you!!